# gcloud scp: Alpha Access Permission required

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I try to use `gcloud alpha compute scp` to transfer files to one of my instances.

I get `- Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'` when executing the command.

The instance is started with `--scopes compute-rw`

Where can I set the required `Alpha Access` permission?

Answer (score 2):

To use of the Alpha release needs your project get white-listed. Instead, use [`copy-files`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files):

```
$ gcloud compute copy-files
```

Or [`scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/scp) which is in beta:

```
$ gcloud beta compute scp
```

Comment: How does a project get white-listed? By Google?